# How Qt platform plugin could be initialized in Google Colab?

Tags: image, qt, google-colaboratory

I got the following error while using Google Colab:

*qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Available platform plugins are: xcb.*

Please help me find a replacement for qt?

Comment: You should change the title of your question to provide more insights. For example `How Qt platform plugin could be initialized in Google Colab?` could be a good candidate.

Also you should include the minimal python code you run in Google Colab that leads to this error.

Answer (score 3):

Having the same problem, and I think I found the answer.
Basically not possible to run QT on the cloud!

"QT is a GUI library that can run only on your local machine. You cannot run it in the cloud and then let it open a QT window on your machine.
You may need to find another labeling library that use web-interface instead."

check this out:

[Could not connect to any X display: Google Colab Run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491808/could-not-connect-to-any-x-display-google-colab-run-time)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Noted and edited, will definitely consider in the my next contributes, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you could make it work with the right platform plugin. By passing for example `-platform vnc` to your application you should be able to start it in "headless mode". (actually your GUI is drawn to a VNC server you can connect to)

Your error is caused by the absence of a window manager, the xcb platform is trying to access.

Comment: Hello, could you please elaborate to your answer. I have a similar problem with GoogleColab. thank you.

Comment: Just run `yourApplication.exe -platform vnc`. If that does not work post your error message here. Just to be clear, it has to be a Qt application.

Comment: this is the command i want to run.
!python3 /content/4DMOS/semantic-kitti-api/visualize_mos.py -platform vnc
And here is the error

WARNING: could not connect to display 
WARNING: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
WARNING: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

Comment: You need to research how to select the plugin in python. The keywords for your search: pyQt, platform plugin, qt platform plugin. Im only programming for C++.